# Stuck on Grub, can't load Ubuntu

Tags: usb-installation

I had RHEL-5.5 installed on my servers with 8 partitions. I wanted to install Ubuntu-12.04. So, I formatted the drive and installed Ubuntu-12.04 through USB. But I am stuck at grub screen. On a black screen "grub" is written there and it sticks there.

Please suggest what to do in order to load Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed the grub in the wrong partition, you will need to boot from the USB and either use tool like Boot Repair, or reinstall ubuntu again making sure you install grub in the right partition.